# PySpark Window function to check based on condition a lag row

Tags: pyspark, window, lag

I would need to take (if present and last) **STAT 200**.
I would like to take its date only if last status and for this case I know how to do it, it's ok.

But i need first to check it (if it not the last status) and then,
if it were not the last, I would like to consider the date of the last state as 200 but only if the next state is not minor (for example 150 as in the next case). In this case I wouldn't want to consider it.

How to do in PySpark? Thank you very much

| ID | STAT | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 17/11/2021 |
| *1* | *200* | *18/11/2021* |
| 1 | 150 | 19/11/2021 |
| 1 | 100 | 20/11/2021 |
| **2** | **200** | **20/11/2021** |

*In this case I don't want to consider ID 1 (status 150 < 200). So I take only ID 2.*

| ID | STAT | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 17/11/2021 |
| **1** | **200** | **18/11/2021** |
| 1 | 350 | 19/11/2021 |
| 1 | 400 | 20/11/2021 |
| **2** | **200** | **20/11/2021** |

*In this case I want to consider status 200 and its details (status 350 > 200 for ID 1; just 200 for ID 2)*

Thank u for support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a default value to the `lead` function and then handle last row with `STAT = 200` and non-last row with `STAT=200` using the same logic.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("TIME")

df.withColumn("LEAD_STAT", F.lead("STAT", default=201).over(window_spec)).filter((F.col("STAT") == 200) & (F.col("LEAD_STAT") > 200)).show()
```

## Example

### Scneario One

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

data = [(1, 100, datetime.strptime("17/11/2021", "%d/%m/%Y"),),
(1, 200, datetime.strptime("18/11/2021", "%d/%m/%Y"),),
(1, 150, datetime.strptime("19/11/2021", "%d/%m/%Y"),),
(1, 100, datetime.strptime("20/11/2021", "%d/%m/%Y"),),
(2, 200, datetime.strptime("20/11/2021", "%d/%m/%Y"),),]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("ID", "STAT", "TIME"))

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("TIME")

df.withColumn("LEAD_STAT", F.lead("STAT", default=201).over(window_spec)).filter((F.col("STAT") == 200) & (F.col("LEAD_STAT") > 200)).show()
```

#### Output

```
+---+----+-------------------+---------+
| ID|STAT|               TIME|LEAD_STAT|
+---+----+-------------------+---------+
|  2| 200|2021-11-20 00:00:00|      201|
+---+----+-------------------+---------+
```

### Scneario Two

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window


data = [(1, 100, datetime.strptime("17/11/2021", "%d/%m/%Y"),),
(1, 200, datetime.strptime("18/11/2021", "%d/%m/%Y"),),
(1, 350, datetime.strptime("19/11/2021", "%d/%m/%Y"),),
(1, 400, datetime.strptime("20/11/2021", "%d/%m/%Y"),),
(2, 200, datetime.strptime("20/11/2021", "%d/%m/%Y"),),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("ID", "STAT", "TIME"))

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("TIME")

df.withColumn("LEAD_STAT", F.lead("STAT", default=201).over(window_spec)).filter((F.col("STAT") == 200) & (F.col("LEAD_STAT") > 200)).show()
```

#### Output

```
+---+----+-------------------+---------+
| ID|STAT|               TIME|LEAD_STAT|
+---+----+-------------------+---------+
|  1| 200|2021-11-18 00:00:00|      350|
|  2| 200|2021-11-20 00:00:00|      201|
+---+----+-------------------+---------+
```

Comment: The code is the same for scenario two, just that the data setup  changes. That said, I have included the data setup and applied the same logic for scenario 2 too to help you test it out easily.

Comment: Thank u for your help! It seems to me an acceptable solution! 
Now I have to figure out how to manage real statuses. Because there are many ID that are the same status but with an additional categorical column that has no order. (example: 200 BC > 200 AX > 200 TD)

Comment: Since it's a categorical column you can replace the categorical value with an integer and use that for comparison.

Comment: It's a brilliant idea! I have too many status but I can try to do it! 
Other question please: can I do a window over partition to find only the ID that have (in partition) at least one status 200? If it has a status 200, take all the partition... otherwise i can drop it without proceed with other calucalation.

Comment: Yes ofcourse there are multiple ways to do it, groupBy `filter stat=200` then select `ID` distinct and then join back with the original DF to get rows with `ID` that had atleast one `STAT 200`, can be done with window too but with a complicated logic, maybe pose a new question and I can include a better answer, since comments are not the best way to go about this.

Comment: It's so clear! So i can proceed creating a flag column with a groupBY, a filter and then a select for ID (dropping duplicates). Then i can join original df. Thank u very much!!!

Comment: It made a typo in my comment, a `groupBy` is not needed, just `filter STAT=200` `select distinct ID` and then join with original df.